# Get path from storage directory inside vue component in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, vue.js, directory, vue-component

I need to get the path from `/storage/app/public` for a image in a `.vue` component, while using `vue-loader` and `vue-router`.

```
<img :src="'/storage/app/public' + user.imageFromDb" />
```

If I go that way, I can't get the image path. But if I try to get an image path from `/public/img`, it will work like a charme.

I want to store all uploads in the `/storage` directory, and I'm using the [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk) `Storage::disk('myDisk')->makeDirectory('path/' . $path);` method.

Is there a possibility to get the path in a clean way? Maybe something like that

```
export default {
    data function() {

        imagePath: '/path/to/storage' + this.user.imageFromDb
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a public path? Your image needs to be publicly available... The public directory is the web root... so anything above that is not public...

Comment: Oh yes sure. The disk, so the directory is public.

Comment: @Serge You‘re so right! The /storage direction is NOT public. I thought, if I set my own „disk“ to public in laravel filesystem, the directory will be reachable from web. Now i‘m storing uploads in /public and everything is fine. Thanks for mind-kick!